# Hibernate recursive mapping parent/child structure - StackOverflowError when retrieve data

Tags: hibernate, recursion, parent-child, hibernate-mapping, jpa-annotations

I am using Hibernate 5.2.7.Final, and native Hibernate API.
I have an Employee entity with recursive relations:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column
    private String firstname;

    @Column
    private String lastname;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={ CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="manager_id")
    private Employee manager;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="manager", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Employee> subordinates = new HashSet<Employee>();
    // setters, getters, constructors
}
```

The following table is created by hibernate:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| employeeId | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| firstname  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| lastname   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| manager_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I persists successfully the manager and the employees with:

```
    Employee manager = new Employee("A", "B");

    Employee employee1 = new Employee("C", "D");
    Employee employee2 = new Employee("E", "E");

    employee1.setManager(manager1);
    employee2.setManager(manager1);

    Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
    employees.add(employee1);
    employees.add(employee2);

    manager.setSubordinates(employees);

    session.save(manager);
```

Now retrieving the employee will cause StackOverFlowError.

```
    Long id = manager.getEmployeeId();

    Query<Employee> query = ss.createQuery("from Employee e where e.employeeId = :employeeId", Employee.class);

    query.setParameter("employeeId", id);

    Employee retrieved = (Employee) query.uniqueResult();
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:396)
at java.lang.Long.toString(Long.java:1032)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at objectModels.Employee.toString(Employee.java:82)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
```

I think the way I can persist such Employee object graph is so convenient. But I have no idea how to retrieve such graph from the table.

Question: how can I meaningfully retrieve Employee information from the underlying table. I think the way around it is to create a new Entity for viewing the Employee table like

```
    public class EmployeeView {
            private Long employeeId;
            private String firstname;
            private String manager_name;
            private Set<String> subordinate_names;
    }
```

Can I achieve this? and how with JPA annotation?

Comment: Can you include the `StackOverflowError` stack trace?  Also, what version of Hibernate are you testing this on as I cannot reproduce this on 5.2.7.Final.

Comment: I have included the stack trace. I think StackOverflowError is caused when employee object is fetched, hibernate try to fetch its managers, and manager in turn have such employee in its subordinates list. I have tried     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `toString()` method in your `Employee`entity.

Since you didn't provide any code, here is a clear example of how this would happen between a more generalized perspective of a `Parent` and `Child`.

```
public class Parent {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent");
  List<Child> children;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append( "Parent{children=" );
    children.forEach( sb::apend );
    sb.append( "}" );
    return sb.toString();
}

public class Child {
  @ManyToOne
  private Parent parent;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Child{parent=" + parent + "}";
  }
}
```

Now somewhere in the code there is this:

```
System.out.println( parent.toString() );
```

This would cause the same overflow problem because the call into `Parent` would delegate down into `Child` which delegates back to `Parent` and the nasty cycle continues.

You need to decide which makes the most logical sense in your case and likely either skip or only print the identifier of the associated entity to avoid this recursive loop.

Comment: You are right. I have such a nasty toString().  Thank you so much for your insight.